# how can I convert a string to a vector in rust?

Tags: string, rust

I would like to receive a:

```
"Hello, I would like to meet you"
```

and convert to:

```
["Hello,", "I", "would", "like", "to", "meet", "you"]
```

how could I make that?

Comment: See the [`split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split) method on strings.

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated method for `str` to do this called [`split()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split). You can then use [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) to put the result in a `Vec`.

In your case:

```
fn main() {
    let original = "Hello, I would like to meet you";
    let split = original.split(' ');
    
    let vec: Vec<_> = split.collect();
    
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```